# Getting null output on executing DECRYPTBYKEY in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm a newbie to stored procedures. I have successfully encrypted the user password to the table. But when I write a decryption SP I'm getting a null output. Please check the SP and point out my mistake

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[temp]
    @EmployeeUserName varchar(20),
    @EmployeePassword varchar(20),
    @Flag varchar(10),
    @Error VARCHAR(10) OUT
AS
BEGIN
    if (@Flag = 'login')
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @EncryptedPasswordfromDatabase varbinary(256)
        DECLARE @DecryptedPassword varchar(20)

        select @EncryptedPasswordfromDatabase = EmployeePassword from employeelogin where EmployeeUserName=@EmployeeUserName

        OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY EmployeeLoginKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE EncryptPasswordCert
        SET @Error = convert(varbinary(20),DECRYPTBYKEY(@EncryptedPasswordfromDatabase))
        RETURN @Error
        CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY EmployeeLoginKey
    END
END
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the Return key word there as you have passed that @Error Parameter as OUTPUT.

**Procedure Definition**

```
USE [Practice]
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[temp]
    @EmployeeUserName varchar(20),
    @EmployeePassword varchar(20),
    @Flag varchar(10),
    @Error VARCHAR(10) OUT
AS
BEGIN
    if (@Flag = 'login')
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @EncryptedPasswordfromDatabase varbinary(256)
        DECLARE @DecryptedPassword varchar(20)

        select @EncryptedPasswordfromDatabase = EmployeePassword from employeelogin where EmployeeUserName=@EmployeeUserName

        OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY EmployeeLoginKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE EncryptPasswordCert
        SET @Error = convert(varbinary(20),DECRYPTBYKEY(@EncryptedPasswordfromDatabase));
-- No Return required
        CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY EmployeeLoginKey    
    END
END
```

**EXECUTE PROC**

```
DECLARE @Error_OUT VARCHAR(10); 

EXECUTE [dbo].[temp]
              @EmployeeUserName = 'Emp Name'
             ,@EmployeePassword = 'Password'
             ,@Flag             = 'some flag'
             ,@Error            =  @Error_OUT OUTPUT --<-- Use the OUTPUT word here
                                                        -- when passing params
```

**RETURN**

Use of `RETURN` key word anywhere in your procedure `stops the execution of code there` and exit. Therefore in your code the SYMMETRIC KEY will never be close once code entered the IF block.

Also RETURN key word can only be used to `return INT datatype`. Your @Error is VARCHAR datatype. It wouldnt work with RETURN key word even if you use it in the correct place in your procedure.